# Installing scipy in virtualenv on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, elastic-beanstalk, virtualenv, pip, flask

I'm using Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk to deploy an example Flask app. I can get a simple "Hello World" app deployed perfectly, but now I'm trying to deploy the app with `scipy` as a requirement.

I've included the necessary packages in my `.ebextensions/`:

```
packages:
    yum:
        gcc-c++: []
        gcc-gfortran: []
        python27-devel: []
        atlas-sse3-devel: []
        lapack-devel: []
        libpng-devel: []
        zlib-devel: []
        postgresql93-devel: []
```

If I leave `scipy` and `numpy` in the `requirements.txt` file, the deploy fails because `numpy` has to be installed before `scipy`.

I can fix this by commenting out `scipy` from my `requirements.txt`, and adding a `container_commands` section to my `.ebextensions`:

```
container_commands:
    01_install_scipy:
        command: "pip install scipy"
```

I don't like this approach because I want all of my requirements to live in my `requirements.txt` file for development purposes. Selectively commenting out pip requirements from the `requirements.txt` file feels wrong and can get complicated if I have a bunch of other libraries that depend on `scipy`.

Additionally, building scipy from source takes a very long time, especially on relatively small EC2 instances. I have tried installing using `yum`, but this leads to using old versions of `scipy` and not having `scipy` in the virtual environment.

So, I have two problems:

1. **requirements.txt:** Is there any way to install `scipy` to my virtual environment that doesn't require me to comment out selective requirements from my `requirements.txt` file?
2. **Speed:** Is there any way to pre-compile scipy and still make it available in the virtual environment?

Answer (score 0):

You should package your application (zip) before to deploy it. This package should include all deps your application need so you don't have to pre-install module when deploying.